# Angular + Express, GET request doesn't work

Tags: angular, express, httprequest

Basically my Angular App should do an HTTP-Get Request and the Express server (which also hosts the angular app) should send an JSON object to the Angular app. Somehow it doesn't work and I have no clue why. Even the first console.log on my Server.js get method wont get called.

Server.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/appTest')));

app.use(bodyParser.json({
  limit: '5mb'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
});
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/appTest/index.html'))

});
app.get("/api/getData", function(req,res) {
  console.log("get123");
  var testObj = {
    "name": "TestName",
    "email": "Test@Email.com",
    "subject": "TestSubject",
    "content": "Some text...",
    "answer": [{
      "date": newDate(Date.now()).toLocaleString(),
      "sender":"Mr.Test",
      "answer":"some text.."
    }]
  }
  console.log("get456");
  res.json(testObj)
});
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running on port 3000!'));
```

The Angular service im using :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DbConnectorService {
  private baseUrl:string = "http://localhost:3000"
  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getAllData() {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + '/api/getData').subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
  }
```

The console.log in the service prints out the following :

```
Response {_body: "<!doctype html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵  <meta ch…="main-es5.js" nomodule></script></body>↵</html>↵", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers
```

[image]

My goal is to get the Object "testObj" from the server to the Angular App with a get request(printing it on the browser console is enough for now). And Im also wondering why the console.logs in the `app.get("/api/getData", function(req,res)` won't get printed. Does that mean that route never gets called? But why?

Comment: if your getting 200 from the server you are getting a response, can you be more specific on what is not working

Comment: My bad sorry. First I want to receive the Object 'testObj' from the server on the Angular Side/service. Second Im wondering why the console.logs in the "app.get("/api/getData", function(req,res).." won't get called. I edited the Post tho

Comment: Try declaring the `app.get('*', (` route **after** the `app.get("/api/getData"` route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When define `app.get('*', function()= {})` it take every HTTP request and handle it by its callback. I can see your response from the api containing HTML data from a file so in this case, your api process this block code, not the `/api/getData`.

```
app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/appTest/index.html'))

});
```